# how we can order browsing in 4 list of words?

Tags: python, list, loops, validation

i have 4 group of word
i intend write a program in python to input a name and brows in 4 group and if find in one's say the group name

```
group1=["anbar","tamirgah kochak","ordogah jahangardi","zamin varzeshi","mohavate sazi","kargah kochak"]
group2=["maskoni","small store","khabgah","mehmansara","asayeshgah","parking tabaghati","kodakestan","dabestan","rahnamaii","dabirstan","honarestan","salon varzesh"]
group3=["daneshsara","fani herfei","daneshgah","namayeshgah","teather","cinema"]
group4=["hospital","mokhaberat","metro","mosque","museum","bank","stadium","airport"]

all_group=[group1, group2, group3,group4]

project_type = input("chose project type: ")
for x in all_group:
    if x==project_type :
        project_area = int(input("inter the area m2 :"))
        price_per_m2 = int(input("inter price per m2 :"))
        print(project_type ,":",x,"=",project_area * price_per_m2,"$ per m2")
    else:
        print("enter another word")
break
```

what i wrote

Comment: What is the problem you have? What happens when you run the code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use a dictionary, and iterate over items:

```
all_group = {"group1":group1, "group2":group2, "group3":group3, "group4":group4}

project_type = input("chose project type: ")
for group_name, group_values  in all_group.items():  
    if project_type in group_values:
        print(group_name)
        ...
```

Comment: thank you Robert. nice answer. but is there any way we get deeper investigation in a list items? i mean not only the name of list in this case group1,group2but also their contents and even more the letter of words (in this case)??? i appreciat you in advance